# Session reset issue ASP:NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with my asp.net website, i login and do some thing that use Session["something"] and all works fine, but sometimes after triggering some events that cause reload of the page, the loading is longer than before and when it's done i have all Sessions[] cleared, and looks like the Session timed out, my user is still logged in (maybe because i've cheked "Remember Me")

my question is: how do i avoid to reset Session?

my web.config ---> sessionState is:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="60">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

timeout's 60 min, but Session reset after like 20/30 min

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: there are too many variables at play here and this would be virtually impossible to diagnose with the information you have provided. The first thing I would ask is to see where Session variables are getting set. 
One reason why using session variables is not recommended for asp.net webforms other than true session level vars is that it is almost impossible to keep track of if their values are getting assigned in multiple places.

Comment: @DaniDev i can post the code where all sessions variables are used but there are a lot of them, but if the site works well, Sessions vars are set correctly, and used correctly, how Sessions auto-reset? i never reset them. i'm newbie, be patient with me

Comment: "but there are a lot of them" - what are you using them for? ;
"Sessions vars are set correctly"  - where are they set?